# Looking for an elegant way to load the messages from the IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, dispatcher

My requirement is to cycle the messages from the `IEnumerable` collection after say x sec interval.
Actually I have a `IEnumerable<Message>` which have say 5 messages and when the screen (WPF) loads I'm showing the first message from the collection and next message will be shown say after x sec and so on.

One solution comes to my mind is to use the dispatcher timer. Any other way to do that same thing?

Comment: You say: 

> ... and when the screen loads ...

What screen? ASP.NET Web screen, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight? The UI makes a difference in the answer.

For example, in WPF you would use Expression Blend to setup a storyboard. But you wouldn't use that in ASP.NET or WinForms.

Comment: what is your target? WPF? Windows Forms? Web? Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK timers are designed exactly for this purpose and perform well in it.
Why want anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reactive extensions to do this. Something like:

```
messages.ToObservable().Delay(new Timespan(0,0,x)).ObserveOn(Dispatcher)
.Subscribe(m => ShowMessage(m));
```

Comment: I don't think this works, exactly -- it delays for x seconds, then spits out all the messages at once.

Comment: I like the idea though -- see my answer for a working example along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is along the lines of Ankur's -- use Reactive extensions to generate a timer-based observable sequence:

```
public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

void QueueMessages(IEnumerable<Message> messages)
{
    int intervalSeconds = 5;

    // generate the observable source
    var enumerator = messages.GetEnumerator();
    var source = Observable.Generate(
            enumerator,                                  // initial value
            i => enumerator.MoveNext(),                  // condition
            i => i,                                      // iterate
            i => enumerator.Current,                     // selector
            i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervalSeconds))  // interval selector
        .ObserveOnDispatcher();

    // subscribe to the source
    source.Subscribe(

        // display messages as they arrive
        message => Messages.Add(message),

        // add a "complete" message when done
        () => Messages.Add(new Message("complete!"))
    );
}
```

Of course, the effect is the same as a DispatcherTimer, but the syntax here is cleaner for enumerating once on each timer tick.